# Redmine Rest API error 'Subject can not be blank'

Tags: php, redmine-api

I am creating issue by using `kbsali redmine api`, I am receiving subject can not be blank error even I am passing subject

```
$result=$client->issue->create([
    'project_id'  => 'projder',
    'subject'     => 'this is subject subject this is subject subject this is subject subject this is subject subject this is subject subject',
    'description' => 'this is subject subject this is subject subject this is subject subject this is subje',
    'assigned_to_id' => '45',
    'priority_id' => $_POST['inputPriority'],
    'uploads'     => array(
        array(
          'token'       => $upload->upload->token,
          'filename'    => $file,
          'description' => 'This is my file description',
          'content_type'=> 'image/png'
        ),
        array(
          'token'       => $uploadoptional->upload->token,
          'filename'    => $optionalUpload,
          'description' => 'Client Attachment',
          'content_type'=> $optionalUploadType
        )
    )
]);



)
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [type] => array
        )

    [error] => Subject cannot be blank
)
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Would it work without transferring attachments?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, redmine subject field rights were not given to the user by using i was sending API request to create ticket.